# How to force CS web to recompile after change to .cshtml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have an ASP.NET (C#) web, and using VS Code as the IDE.   I discovered that if I make a change to a non-CS file, e.g, .cshtml, .css, I have to open a .cs file and make an insignificant change and close it to force the web to recompile.

Is there a way {plug in or something} that will recompile the .cs either through a key combination or something instead of the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Recompile what, exactly? If you change a .cshtml file and reload the page you will see the changes

Comment: No.   

Maybe it's because I'm using VS Code to do the editing.  If I make changes to cshtml, or .css files it won't see the change unless I make an insignificant change to the .cs file (add/remove a space) and re-save it.   Then it will recompile and show me the change.    

I'm using NancyFX as my routing engine.   I don't know if that might be the issue.